# Problems with Eclipse-exported files running in terminal

Tags: java, eclipse, directory, export, package

I'm having a rather hair-pulling issue regarding how Eclipse treats packages once exported.

For a university assignment, we are creating a sort of hangman program. One requirement of this is that we use packages to organise our classes. We also have to provide our source code/.class files so that it can be run from command line.

The problem is that Eclipse uses the project directory as the working directory for all files, which means that once the project has been exported, all the *import* statements fail because the working directory is now the directory the file is in.

There is a similar problem with sound and image resource locations.

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Comment: As long as you keep the directory structure the same the imports should work regardless of the root directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can do multiple things; however the fastest and most efficient is to use the command prompt and manually set the directory.
Here Is How I Would Do It:

`cd C:\Users\*NAME*\workspace\*PROJECT_NAME*\bin
java *MAIN_CLASS_NAME*`

This will only work if you are not creating a GUI, however from what you have said it does not seem like you are.

You can also extract the directory from your workspace and compile from the desktop:

*Move C:\Users*NAME*\workspace*PROJECT_NAME*\bin*NAME_OF_CLASSES*
to the desktop and all you have to do is:

`cd C:\Users\*NAME*\Desktop\*PACKAGE*
java "MAIN_CLASS_NAME"`

It's also possible; in fact likely, you mean to import something, and it is failing, this method will also work.

P.S All The Code Listed Is Done VIA The Command Prompt...

I Hope this helps :)